# While loop with result from function - BASH

Tags: bash, whiptail

I would like to compare the result (0 or 1) of a function in a while loop. Function `validmask` checks whether the entered input is in mask format. If so I get `1`, and if not I get `0`.

I want to run the `mask=$(whiptail ...)` command and check the value of `$mask with the`validmask` function until it returns a valid mask.

My problem is that I can't run the function again; my script exits after a single run. I know I have to put the function in the if statement, but I don't know how. Or is there better solution?

Here is the code:

```
if validmask $mask; then stat2='1'; else stat2='0'; fi
while validmask
do
   if [[ $stat2 == 0 ]]; then
        mask=$(whiptail --title "xx" --inputbox --nocancel "Bad entry" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
   fi
done
```

**ADDED**
Function validmask

```
function validmask()
{
    local  mask=$1
    local  stat2=1

    if [[ $mask =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS='.'
        mask=($mask)
        IFS=$OIFS
        [[ ${mask[0]} -le 255 && ${mask[1]} -le 255 \
            && ${mask[2]} -le 255 && ${mask[3]} -le 255 ]]
        stat2=$?
    fi
    return $stat2
}
```

Also in loop while should be check if mask is valid or not. I got **above**     `if validmask $mask; then stat2='1'; else stat2='0'; fi` 
code what checks empty input.

```
while [[ -z "$mask" ]]
do
   mask=$(whiptail --title "xx" --inputbox --nocancel "Mask" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
done
```

If I start my script I am able to fill in just one time a mask. A function validmask is not executed again.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the entire script. Where is `validmask` defined? How does it work? What is it doing in the while loop?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It's still not very clear though. What exactly are you looping for? Do you want to repeat the `whiptail` command until you get a valid mask? Do you want to repeat it for ever?

Comment: Yes exactly. Until I get valid mask. Plus input won't be empty.

Comment: Your `validmask()` function doesn't validate correctly.

Comment: @pawel7318 what do you mean not correctly? It returns 1 if mask is valid (e.g. 255.255.255.0), returns 0 (2555555.555.552.99)

Comment: How about 100.0.0.0 or 255.0.255.0 ?

Comment: @pawel7318 - are those invalid?

Comment: @mikeserv - if we're talking about netmask (I assume we do) than yes, those are invalid.

Comment: @pawel7318 - the only valid netmasks are `(255.)*((2(24|4[08]|5[0245])|1(92|28)|0).)` is that right? And the value must always descend, and there can be never be more than a single octet which is not either 255 or 0, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the `whiptail` command once and save the mask. Check if it is valid and, if not, repeat until it is:

```
## Get the 1st mask
mask=$(whiptail --title "xx" --inputbox --nocancel "Bad entry" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
## If it isn't valid, repeat until it is
until validmask "$mask"; do
    mask=$(whiptail --title "xx" --inputbox --nocancel "Bad entry" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is:

```
while validmask
do ...
```

Nothing ever happens there - you call your function without any arguments. And so it returns false and the loop stops.

The next problem is you want to run your function *until* the return is valid. To do that, you need to use `until`. I managed to overlook this before.

You need to drop the first `if` statement and just do:

```
until validmask "$mask"
do    mask=$(get_new_value)
done
```

The `until` loop is the boolean negation of the `while`. It will run until the command it runs returns true.

It can also be written:

```
while ! validmask "$mask"
do    mask=$(get_new_mask)
done
```

You might do the assignment / test at once:

```
unset mask
until validmask "${mask:=$(get_new_value)}"
do    mask=
done
```

Another problem is that your `validmask` function fails to fully validate for a lot of edge cases - especially those which include `[*?`. I think you should just be using `case` and nevermind all of the ancillary splitting and variable declarations.

Just rule out bad values:

```
validmask()
    case    "${1##*[!0-9.]*}"       in
    (.*|*.|*..*|*.*.*.*.*|*[!.][!.][!.][!.]*) ! :;;
    (*[3-9][!.][!.]*|*2[6-9][!.]*|*25[6-9]*)  ! :;;
    (*.*.*.*)       ;;              (*)       ! :;;
    esac
```

A little demo:

```
for mask in              \
         0.0.0.0         \
         0.0.0.          \
         0.0.0.1233      \
         0.0.0.233       \
         0.0..233        \
         0.0.2.233       \
         0.5555.2.233    \
         0.55.2.233      \
         .55.2.233       \
         1.55.2.233      \
         255.255.255.255 \
         255.255.256.255
do    validmask "$mask"
      printf "%-16.16s: %.$?0s%.$((!$?*4))s\n%.d" \
             "$mask" bad good  "0$(($?*8))"
      printf "printf's return:\t $?\n\n"
done  2>/dev/null
```

---

```
0.0.0.0         : good
printf's return:     0

0.0.0.          : bad
printf's return:     1

0.0.0.1233      : bad
printf's return:     1

0.0.0.233       : good
printf's return:     0

0.0..233        : bad
printf's return:     1

0.0.2.233       : good
printf's return:     0

0.5555.2.233    : bad
printf's return:     1

0.55.2.233      : good
printf's return:     0

.55.2.233       : bad
printf's return:     1

1.55.2.233      : good
printf's return:     0

255.255.255.255 : good
printf's return:     0

255.255.256.255 : bad
printf's return:     1
```

Here's another version of `validmask()` which, as I think, actually validates the masks. I didn't realize before that the netmasks were so restrictive.

```
validmask()
    case    ."${1##*[!.0124589]*}".      in
    (*.*.*.*.*.*.*|*[!.][!.][!.][!.]*) ! :;;
    (*[!.25]*.[!0]*|*.[!012]*|*0[!.]*) ! :;;
    (*1[!29]*|*1?[!28]*|*98*|*.2?.*)   ! :;;
    (*4[!.08]*|*[.2][25][!245]*)       ! :;;
    (.*.*.*.*.)  echo "$1";; (*)       ! :;;
    esac

a=-1 b=0 c=0 d=0
for o in a b c d
do    while  [ "$(($o+=1))" -lt 1000 ] ||
             ! : "$(($o=255))"
      do     validmask "$a.$b.$c.$d"
done; done
```

---

```
0.0.0.0
128.0.0.0
192.0.0.0
224.0.0.0
240.0.0.0
248.0.0.0
252.0.0.0
254.0.0.0
255.0.0.0
255.128.0.0
255.192.0.0
255.224.0.0
255.240.0.0
255.248.0.0
255.252.0.0
255.254.0.0
255.255.0.0
255.255.128.0
255.255.192.0
255.255.224.0
255.255.240.0
255.255.248.0
255.255.252.0
255.255.254.0
255.255.255.0
255.255.255.128
255.255.255.192
255.255.255.224
255.255.255.240
255.255.255.248
255.255.255.252
255.255.255.254
255.255.255.255
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `if` statement to your `while` loop.

```
while true
do
   if ! validmask $mask; then
        mask=$(whiptail --title "xx" --inputbox --nocancel "Bad entry" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
   else
       break
   fi
done
```

Comment: Shoudn't it be `while true`?

Comment: I used your code but I got an error "command not found" I guess I got wrong function. I am enclosing a screen of code function. [link]http://postimg.org/image/jmkr7a8mb/

Comment: @muru Meanwhile I used your advice I get looped.

Comment: My bad, I've fixed the code.